# Mod rewrite order

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have a visitor entering by default to a certain dir but I have multiple rewrites already and I can't get it to work. Basically, here are the rules :

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

No directory ? redirect to /all

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /all [R]
```

Have '/all' as directory ? rewrite now to real php url

```
RewriteRule ^(all)$ index.php?somestuff=not_important_here [L,QSA]
```

Now when i test : I navigate to my site www.somesite.com, which rewrite to www.somesite.com/all but now the browser says that my page has an indirect loop. How to fix it so it goes from '/' to '/all' and then rewrite the url again for php ?

Thanks

edit : removed the extra rules, now only using what's here.

Comment: Why don't you use `DirectoryIndex` to send your visitor to `/all` by default?

Comment: I don't believe this couldn't work as /all is not a directory, it's only a virtual dir to rewrite the url, or I don't know how to...

Comment: My mistake, that's not what you want to do.

Comment: You should post your `RewriteCond` lines so we can see what matches your conditions.

Comment: I removed them all and only use now the ones here, will edit a bit main post

Comment: Put this line RewriteRule ^(all)... [L,QSA]
before RewriteRule ^(.*)$... [R]. that way if it doesn't match "all" it falls through, otherwise the first condition will match on "all" too

Comment: now does : www.somesite.com -> www.somesite.com/all -> www.somesite.com/all?somestuff=not_important_here :(